# Comment not posted when voting to close as duplicate

Tags: bug, status-norepro, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

I just added a duplicate close vote + duplicate question to this question on Stack Overflow:

[How to debug FinderSync extension in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584944/how-to-debug-findersync-extension-in-xcode)

The vote was recorded:

> close (1)

But the question did NOT receive an auto-comment:

> Does this answer your question? [question]
> -- or --
> Possible duplicate of [question]

The duplicate-target was also not listed in the list of Linked Questions.

Why wasn't the comment posted or the dupe-target linked?

I refreshed the page *immediately* after voting as duplicate and never saw a comment.

Comment: That is odd. The comment was never posted there. Your close vote was recorded, however. I don’t know why the auto-comment was not generated.

Comment: I’m pretty sure we were looking at this and it does get posted but if the OP says it’s not a duplicate, the comment is deleted... and it’s apparently deleted through the wrong route so there’s no indication that the comment ever existed, even to mods. At minimum, we need to change how the comment is deleted.

Comment: @Catija I refreshed the page immediately and the comment was definitely **never** posted. Unless the OP caught it in ~1 second after my post or something crazy like that.