# No comment posted when question is closed as off-topic because ... > other

Tags: bug, status-norepro, closed-questions, automatic-comments

When closing a question (as a mod, so binding vote) using Close > Off-topic because ... > Other and entering a comment to explain why it was closed the question get closed but the explanatory comment does not get posted.

Example question: [Unplugging and Plugging DisplayPort while PC is on](https://superuser.com/questions/1531890/unplugging-and-plugging-displayport-while-pc-is-on)

The comment was manually added by me after the question was closed as the comment added in the close dialog did not get added.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image]

Possibly related issue: [Comment not posted when voting to close as duplicate - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344867/comment-not-posted-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate)

Comment: Can you provide a question where this happened for reference? Might make it easier to see what went wrong for the team.

Comment: @Mast Good idea. Done.

Comment: Perhaps the same issue, Flagging a dupe as a low rep don't add comment either.

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes, saw that. It may well be the same underlying problem.

Comment: This isn't limited to just mods; I've experienced this problem as well.

Comment: I think this might be intentional as when our community closed [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535562/249968) post with a custom close reason (under off-topic section) the same thing happened as yours. Can you share a link to the post mentioning if this should not be the case?

Comment: @JohanLiebert It's not intentional, it's broken behaviour. The whole point of a custom close reason is to provide a asker with some custom guidance as to why it was closed if one of the standard close reasons is not applicable. Without the comment it's like saying "Your question is closed but I'm not going to tell you why". **If** it is intentional then that close reason should be removed.